# Error in reading html to data frame in Python “html5lib not found”

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, html5lib

I've come accross the following error about html5lib when trying to read an html data frame.

Here is the code:

```
!pip install html5lib
!pip install lxml
!pip install beautifulSoup4

import html5lib
import lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

table_list = pd.read_html("http://www.psmsl.org/data/obtaining/")
```

This is the error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-e24654a0a301> in <module>()
----> 1 table_list = pd.read_html("http://www.psmsl.org/data/obtaining/")

/home/sage/sage-8.0/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/html.pyc in read_html(io, match, flavor, header, index_col, skiprows, attrs, parse_dates, tupleize_cols, thousands, encoding, decimal, converters, na_values, keep_default_na)
    913                   thousands=thousands, attrs=attrs, encoding=encoding,
    914                   decimal=decimal, converters=converters, na_values=na_values,
--> 915                   keep_default_na=keep_default_na)

/home/sage/sage-8.0/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/html.pyc in _parse(flavor, io, match, attrs, encoding, **kwargs)
    737     retained = None
    738     for flav in flavor:
--> 739         parser = _parser_dispatch(flav)
    740         p = parser(io, compiled_match, attrs, encoding)
    741 

/home/sage/sage-8.0/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/html.pyc in _parser_dispatch(flavor)
    680     if flavor in ('bs4', 'html5lib'):
    681         if not _HAS_HTML5LIB:
--> 682             raise ImportError("html5lib not found, please install it")
    683         if not _HAS_BS4:
    684             raise ImportError(

ImportError: html5lib not found, please install it
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you read the error message, you don't have `html5lib` installed. Do:

```
pip install html5lib
```

in your terminal.

---

If you are calling from jupyter notebook (just like you did with `!`), try to restart the kernel in order to have the packages loaded.

Comment: Are you running your code in jupyter notebook? If yes, have you tried to restart the kernel?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Jupyter. Just restarted the kernel and run fine now. Thanks Yilun ;)

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact error show up while trying to read a saved .htm file using Spyder IDE.

This code displayed html5lib error:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_html("F:\xxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\aaaa.htm")
```

I knew I had html5lib installed and working correctly because I had other scripts that worked.

For whatever reason, file path needed to be a string literal (putting an r in front of the file path).

This code works for me:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_html(r"F:\xxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\aaaa.htm")
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error when I gave the wrong path to the local file I was trying to open. So also be sure that you're pointing to the right place!